# Django template language "If" statement with many "and"

Tags: python, django, if-statement

Basically i want to add a class to a div based on whether some variables have content or not.

**This is the If statement:**

```
<div class="search__container
    {% if images == true and blogs != True and parks != True %} 
        only-images 
    {% elif blogs == true and images != True and parks != True %} 
        only-blog
    {% elif parks == true and blogs != True and images != True %} 
        only-parks
    {% elif parks == true and blogs == true and images != True %} 
        only-parks-blogs
    {% elif parks == true and images == true and blogs != True %} 
        only-parks-images
    {% elif images == true and blogs == true and parks != True %} 
        only-images-blogs 
    {% endif %}"
>
```

This way it's not adding any class under any circumstances.

If instead i remove the `==` and replace the `!=` with `is not` it'll always take the first if as True and add the class `only-images`

Comment: Why some of the "True" are not capitalized?

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov I capitalized them and the problem persists

Comment: generally you can remove the 'True'. Just `if images` instead of `if images == True`. For the negative use `and not blogs`

Comment: Generally speaking, complex conditions can be done in the views.py and passed through to your template in the "context". Then you can just check single booleans like "images_no_blogs_no_parks". "images_blogs_no_parks" etc. Also means you could reuse the conditions elsewhere if needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using == and != with boolean True/False is no longer advised in python. Try this

```
<div class="search__container
    {% if images and not blogs and not parks %} 
        only-images 
    {% elif blogs and not images and not parks %} 
        only-blog
    {% elif parks and not blogs and not images %} 
        only-parks
    {% elif parks and blogs and not images %} 
        only-parks-blogs
    {% elif parks and images and not blogs %} 
        only-parks-images
    {% elif images and blogs and not parks %} 
        only-images-blogs 
    {% endif %}"
>
```

Otherwise, consider putting these conditions into single line boolean variables in the context passed to the template (views.py) and just validate "if images_no_logs_no_parks" etc

Comment: That's good thing to know! But can you elaborate why is that? why is Using == and != with Boolean True/False is no longer advised in python?

Comment: Unless you are typing your python, a variable may be an integer 0, or 1. Image x = 1, x == True = True, x is True = False. If you want strict boolean checking, use Is - if you're happy with 0 or 1 being evaluated as boolean values, then == and != is fine.